# Damsel in Distress seeking creative escape from Ravenloft to Mystara

Tags: adnd-2e, ravenloft

My group is trapped wandering the Mists of Ravenloft currently and I am looking for creative suggestions on returning to our home in Mystara ASAP. In the current realm we are in, there isn't an obvious Lord that we could go to, and it is looking like we are lining up a fight with the Drow... not a great plan because my character is newly wed and in a "delicate" state.

We have two mages, a psionicist, a fighter, and a boatload of rogues. I think we are all level 10-15. That's right, not a single healer/priest/paladin.

We have a few *wishes*, but the GM says that will not get us out of there. We also have the *Deck of Many Things*, but I'm hesitant to pull it out in Ravenloft. Are there any creative ideas for escape, and/or how to use wishes to find the way home – for the newlyweds at least, preferably in 3 months game time or less.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Good title.

Comment: I think y'all are right and it is up to the GM, I was just hoping there was a more clever way I had not thought of yet. So the character sunk to playing cards (Deck of Many Things) with Loki, high card wins, the character takes both card effects if she loses...we'll see how this turns out.

Comment: If the DM is the only one who wants to stay in Ravenloft, you could organize a player mutiny, then find or elect another DM.

Comment: It's been a while, but I think the Vistani had at least a limited way to go between the planes.

Answer (score 18):

### Resolve the Dramatic Conflict

Whether this will work for you depends entirely on your GM and how he sees the Ravenloft setting.

One interpretation is that people are drawn through the mists to take part in a mystery play that shows them and the Lord the consequences of that Lord's evil. The only way out of a domain in this case is to finish the play.

A story I can see happening with the details you've given here (and there's no reason to assume I'm right) is this:

1. The Lord was banished here for having an affair with a married woman and killing her gruesomely when she tried to go back to her husband.
2. You are now to be the central piece of the retelling of this story with the characters as actors.
3. The Drow are an early event, perhaps in a climactic battle, the Lord rescued his great love from Drow captivity. He does the same thing here and begins to woo you.
4. You cannot fall in love with him (or if you do, he thinks you can't) and anger him greatly.
5. Your party does something clever to bring the great contrast between the Lords great love for the original target of his anger and his actions.
6. The emotions fuelling the magic holding the domain together subside, forcing the domain to shatter and fade back into the mist. The party is returned to Mystara.

### Stay Hopeful

Whatever happens to your characters, they shouldn't lose hope and begin to fear. Fear is the mind-killer.

Answer (score 11):

I'm afraid there's just no way for a party to escape Ravenloft if their DM doesn't want them to leave. There are no mechanics that could get you out of there without your DM's approval, and, in game, there are no known and not even remotely reliable methods - no spells, no special abilities, no nothing - that would work. There might be portals back to your plane of origin... if your DM planted some around on her map for you. (Or hasn't erased them from the "official" maps... which, as far as I can remember, haven't really featured any anyway.)

**It really is up to your DM. Otherwise there's no escape from the *Realm of Terror*.**

Sorry.

Let's hope some other answer proves me wrong, though. :)